# Are there any Django packages to create signed urls for Google Cloud Storage resources?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing a fairly simply photo app using django-rest-framework for the API and django-storages for the storage engine. The front end is being written in Vue.js. I have the uploading part working, and now I'm trying to serve up the photos. As now seems obvious when the browser tries to load the images from GCS, I just get a bunch of 403 Forbidden errors. I did some reading up on this and it seems that the best practice in my case would be to generate signed urls that expire in some amount of time. I haven't been able to find a package for this, which is what I was hoping for. Short of that, it's not clear to me precisely how to do this in Django.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a working code in django 1.11 with python3.5.**

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage


class CloudStorageURLSigner(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_video_signed_url(bucket_name, file_path):
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
        )
        bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(file_path)
        signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            method='PUT',
            expiration=1545367030, #epoch time
            content_type='audio/mpeg', #change_accordingly
            credentials=creds
        )
        return signed_url
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I removed the method and the content type

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/storage)

Installation:

```
pip install google-cloud-storage
```

Also, make sure to refer to [API Documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html) as you need more things.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I found a function in there called `generate_signed_url`, which is exactly what I need. Where would you recommend using this in a django-rest-framework app? I'm thinking of using it in `views.py`...

Comment: @EvanZamir depends on your case. If it is that view specific, than views.py it is. If it is a part of some business logic, you may want to put it inside a model method.

Comment: Take a look at this: [python signed url](https://github.com/ardinusawan/storage-signedurls-python). I fork the original repo and made some change. And I put that code as a service in my django app

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this problem by using `to_representation` in `serializers.py`:

```
from google.cloud.storage import Blob
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('myBucket')

    def to_representation(self, value):
        try:
            blob = Blob(name=value.name, bucket=bucket)
            signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))
            return signed_url
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Evan Zamir's answer, instead of reassigning `client` and `bucket` you can get them from Django's `default_storage` (this will save time since these are already available).

This is in **settings.py**

```
from datetime import timedelta
from google.oauth2 import service_account

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('credentials.json')
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
GS_BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket"
GS_EXPIRATION = timedelta(seconds=60)
```

In **serializers.py**

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from google.cloud.storage import Blob
from rest_framework import serializers

class SignedURLField(serializers.FileField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        try:
            blob = Blob(name=value.name, bucket=default_storage.bucket)
            signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=default_storage.expiration)
            return signed_url
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            return value
```

You can use this class in your serializer like this,

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = SignedURLField()
```

Note: Do not provide `GS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'publicRead'` if you want signed URLs as it creates public URLs (that do not expire)